# Are flat-free tires any good on a heavy duty garden cart

Tags: equipment

I have an older popular brand of heavy duty garden cart with pneumatic tires. I had problems keeping them inflated within a year, and by year 5 I had resorted to tire sealant to keep them from losing pressure for a day.

I notice that this popular brand now sells a cart with an equivalent rating with flat-free tires. Since I am apparently incapable of (or unwilling to put in the effort) maintaining these tires, I wonder what the implications of running this type of tire on a cart with a rating of 1200+lbs is.

Will mobility or stability be severely impacted?

Answer (score 3):

My experience is only with wheelbarrows and refrigerator trolleys.

The solid tyres are heavier, and slightly less elastic.

So when going over bumps and stones a bit of energy is lost.

No change in stability.

Comment: FWIW, I've had a flat-free tire on a wheelbarrow for over 15 year and love it. No maintenance issues whatsoever, but, like you said, the "ride" is a bit bumpier.

Comment: Possibly you can just change the wheels (without changing the cart). And so you have more choices (more durable tires but not solid)